# AS3 How to assign value of an array to the Keys of an object?

Tags: actionscript-3, eval

I think this is Eval-related.

Here, I have an array of unknown length in run-time.
Say, for example, i wish to assign the values from the array as the KEYS of the object, as below:

```
var myArr:Array = ['a','b','c',...]; //unknown length
var finalValue:int = 20;
var myObj:Object = new Object();

assignValueToObject(); 

//logics of assignValueToObject function
/*
   //TODO.. black box
*/

//In the end, myObj has the value stored and can be accessed like this
myObj["a"]["b"]["c"][...] = 20;
```

I am not sure if i need to resort to [eval.hurlant](http://eval.hurlant.com/), I wish there is a simple way of doing this (either recursion or sth)

Comment: I don't understand what "myObj["a"]["b"]["c"][...] = 20" means.  I've never seen this syntax in AS3.  Maybe that's just me because I'm fairly new to AS3, but that's not how I've ever seen it done.  I would expect this to throw all sorts of errors.  Because you are setting an object equal to an integer.  What could you possibly mean by this?  An object can not `=` an integer.  Or do you mean there are 20 properties in the object?  This is very confusing

Comment: maybe you mean to write it like `myObj = {"a":String,"b":String,"c":String,..."t":String};`

Comment: @NealDavis
myObj is an object which contains another object (multi-layer).
The value of myObj["a"] is an Object which contains the key "b" and the value of another Object which contains the key "c" and ...

You may consider it as an JSON format:
{
  "a": {
      "b": {
         "c" : {
        ...
        }
     }
  }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a for loop to iterate over the elements of the array and create the objects except for the last element of the array, which should not be an object but the desired value. Code untested.

```
var myArr:Array = ['a','b','c',...]; //unknown length
var finalValue:int = 20;
var myObj:Object = new Object();

// variable that holdsthe msot recently created sub-object
var currentObject = myObj;

// create nested objects up to the second last property name
for (var index:int = 0; index < myArr.length -1; ++i)
{
    currentObject = currentObject[element] = {};
}

// add value to last property
currentObject[myArr[myArr.length -1]] = finalValue;
```

Of course, if you want to insert many such values you have to check if the nested object structure already contains some of the properties to avoid overriding those existing ones.

I have to say this looks quite convoluted and there's a high chance that the actual problem you are trying to solve can be solved a lot more elegantly than by having property names as strings in an array.

Answer (score 1):

@null is right as usual, I just added this example to realize the big figure.
You may also initialize this in a loop, so You will able to make what You want (as null suggested You)...

```
var myArray:Array = ["a", "b", "c"];
var mySecondArray:Array = ["a", "b", "c"];
var myValues:Array = ["first element", "secondt element", "third element"];
var relValues:Array = [150, 75, 500];
var indexedValues:Array = [1, 2, 3];
var myObject:Object;
var mySecondObject:Object;
function converArraytToObject(myArray:Array, myValues:Array):Object{
    var o:Object=new Object();
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < myArray.length; i ++){
        o[myArray[i].toString()] = myValues[i].toString();
    }
    return o;
}  
trace(myObject["a"]);
// outputs "first element"
trace(myObject["b"]);
// outputs "second element"
trace(myObject["c"]);
// outputs "third element"
// or
trace(" ***UNSORTED");
for (var j in myObject){
    trace ("index name = [" + j + "] = " +myObject[j]);
}
// or
trace(" ***SORTED by index");
for (var k = 0 ; k < myArray.length ; k++){
    trace ("index name = [" + myArray[k] + "] = " + myObject[myArray[k]]);
}
//or
trace(" ***UNSORTED");
for (var l in mySecondObject){
    trace ("index name = [" + l + "] = " + mySecondObject[l]);
}
//or
trace(" ***SORTED by index");
for (var m = 0 ; m < myArray.length ; m++){
    trace ("index name = [" + myArray[m] + "] = " + mySecondObject[myArray[m]]);
}
```

OUTPUT :

If you want to store the same instances of a Class, I suggest You to use the Vector Class in place of Array.

```
first element
secondt element
third element
    ***UNSORTED
index name = [c] = third element
index name = [a] = first element
index name = [b] = secondt element
    ***SORTED by index
index name = [a] = first element
index name = [b] = secondt element
index name = [c] = third element
    ***UNSORTED
index name = [c] = 3
index name = [a] = 1
index name = [b] = 2
    ***SORTED by index
index name = [a] = 1
index name = [b] = 2
index name = [c] = 3
```

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Arrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html)

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Associative arrays, maps, and dictionaries](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/associative-arrays.html)

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Vectors and ByteArrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals)